# Docusign get Envelope Activity history

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement to Get the Document History(Activity History) from  docusign and Display in Pega Screen.
Do we have any Service for getting this info ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [listAuditEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents/) api to get the envelope audit events for the specified envelope.

> GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events